# How to combine object const to be displayed in modal from API?

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of code such as `image.alt = result.title` and `image.alt = result.explanation`. How do I combine the explanation to the title?

```
// Image
const image = document.createElement("img");
image.src = result.url;
image.alt = result.title
image.loading = "lazy";
image.classList.add("card-img-top");
```

Apologies for the newbie question

Comment: Are you saying that you want both the title and the explanation to be set as the title of the image? You can use string concatenation. That is a `+` in JS.

Answer (score 1):

You have to concat 2 strings. In Javascript, you could do it with `+` operator like that:

```js
image.alt = result.title + ' ' + result.explanation;
```

As you see in the example, I've also added `' '` which is space between two values.